# Module for menu positions

Tags: 8, navigation

Are there any modules for custom menu positions like [Menu position](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_position) for D8?

I am trying to make custom content types that show up in various places in menus based on certain rules.

For example, content type "main navigation item" shows up under the main navigation menu.

A second content type "landing page" has an entity field that defines its parent in "main navigation item" and accordingly shows up nested inside that menu item.

Alternatively, if there are suggestions to go about it differently, I'd love any advice!